# Custom Export Excel to text file

Tags: excel, csv

Is there a way, or a script, that will allow me to take a single **column** of data from an Excel file, and export it to a text file so that each field is separated by a comma and word space—in a single action. Using the Save As csv in Excel still requires you to open the file in an editor and perform a search/replace to achieve this but that requires a second, and needless, step.

The result I'm looking for when exporting a COLUMN from Excel would look like this:

field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field, field

Comment: The only way you will get this in a single step is to write (or record) some VBA/Macro that will copy the column, paste-special transpose, then save that worksheet as a csv file. I would suggest recording the macro first and then you can edit to customize the naming of the csv file and anything else special that you might want.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

Supply your own filepath and filename.  Assumes data starts at row 2 in col B in Sheet1, but you can change these variables to suit in the code.

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fName As String, Txt1 As String
Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long, Rw As Long
Dim Col As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
fName = "C:\yourpath\yourfilename.csv"
fRow = 2
Col = 2
Txt1 = ""

    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

        Open fName For Output As #1

            For Rw = fRow To lRow
                Txt1 = .Range(.Cells(Rw, Col), .Cells(Rw, Col))
                    If Rw = lRow Then
                        Print #1, Txt1
                    Else
                        Print #1, Txt1 & ", ";
                    End If
            Next Rw

        Close #1

        MsgBox ".csv file exported"

    End With
End Sub
```

There is a tutorial [here](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/14/vba-excel-writing-to-a-text-file/) if you want further explanation.

Comment: Sorry but are you really sure it is on that line?  There seems little scope for a syntax error there and I can't even force one.  Just for completeness, this code does work OK with a column of data in Col B.  Presumably you copied and pasted the code from here?

Comment: I slightly modified it so that it should run on an open worksheet—not sure how to  add it here

Comment: OK Paul first things first: with a column of data in col B on a Sheet called 'Sheet1' did the original code run and produce your csv file? Did you get the syntax error before or after your mods?  Are you still getting the same syntax error.  Are you sure you have got data in Col A after your mods?

Comment: First: No; Syntax Error: after mods See screen shot

Comment: I guess it won't let me post a screenshot

Comment: Hello Paul.  We need to get a stake in the ground somewhere with this.  Perhaps we could concentrate on getting the original code running for you, un-modded and with a column of text in Col B say B2:B50, and you manually adding fName.  I know this works; and then we can move on to your mods nd specific requirements.

Comment: Ok I have it working. I took off the csv extension and then get the text file I need with each field separated by the comma and word space.    However, the Excel files supplied come with a custom name for each worksheet so I can't use Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. Is there a way to run this so 1) it ignores the worksheet name but 2) picks it up for naming the new saved file?

Comment: That's great well done.  Suggest you get familiar with manipulating the Worksheets collection to identify your source worksheet, get its name into a variable and then the line becomes 'Set ws = Sheets(wsnamevariable)' without the quotes.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Not sure what "manipulating the Worksheet collection" means. Is "identify the source worksheet" the one that's open or the entire Excel file containing several worksheets? In my case every worksheet across all the Excel files will be named differently. Then where =does the 'Set ws..." go?

Comment: Ok Paul no worries.  I think you need to take a view on whether this answer has met your original Q and close this thread. Compose another question detailing more closely your requirements for using other files and I for one will be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sub WriteCSVFile()

' Declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fName As String, Txt1 As String
Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long, Rw As Long
Dim Col As Long

' Get active sheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' Ask user for output file
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename()

' Stop processing if no file specified
If fName = "False" Then Exit Sub

' Start row
fRow = 1

' Start column
Col = 1

' Output temp
Txt1 = ""

```
With ws
    ' Get data from sheet
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Open output file
    Open fName For Output As #1

        ' Loop rows of data
        For Rw = fRow To lRow
            ' Store data in temp
            Txt1 = .Range(.Cells(Rw, Col), .Cells(Rw, Col))
                ' Check if end of dataset and write data to output accordingly 
                If Rw = lRow Then
                    Print #1, Txt1
                Else
                    Print #1, Txt1 & ", ";
                End If
        Next Rw

    ' Close output file
    Close #1

     ' Alert user of completion
    MsgBox ".csv file exported"

End With
```

End Sub